# seaborn rc parameters for set_context and set_style

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

In the tutorial for setting up the aesthetics of your plots, there are a few different methods:

1. `set_style`
2. `set_context`
3. `axes_style`

Each one of these accepts an `rc` keyword parameter dictionary. In each individual API page for the above three functions, it says:

> ***rcdict, optional:***
>   Parameter mappings to override the values in the preset seaborn style dictionaries. **This only updates parameters that are considered part of the style definition**.

Back in the tutorial page, under `axes_style` it goes on to say exactly how you can see what parameters are available for the `rc` dictionary for this one function:

> *If you want to see what parameters are included, you can just call the function with no arguments, which will return the current settings:*

However, using this on the other functions always returns `None`. So, for example, I am using the following mix of matplotlib and seaborn 
to set parameters:

```
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,10]
viz_dict = {
    'axes.titlesize':18,
    'axes.labelsize':16,
} 
sns.set_context("notebook", rc=viz_dict)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
```

I also noticed that putting my dictionary in the `set_style` method does nothing, while, at least for those parameters, it only works in `set_context`. This means that they each have mutually exclusively characteristics that can be edited. However, this is not outlined anywhere in the docs.

I want to know which one of these three functions will accept a parameter for `figsize`. I'd also be curious to see what else they accept that might help me fine-tune things. My goal is to exclusively use the seaborn interface as often as possible. I don't need the fine tune control of things matplotlib provides, and often find it awkward anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear that the answer is 'none of the above'. The valid keys for `set_style` and `set_context` are listed [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/rcmod.py#L14):

```py
_style_keys = [
    "axes.facecolor", "axes.edgecolor",
    "axes.grid", "axes.axisbelow", "axes.labelcolor",

    "figure.facecolor", "grid.color", 
    "grid.linestyle", "text.color",

    "xtick.color", "ytick.color",
    "xtick.direction", "ytick.direction", 
    "lines.solid_capstyle",

    "patch.edgecolor", "patch.force_edgecolor",

    "image.cmap", "font.family", "font.sans-serif",

    "xtick.bottom", "xtick.top",
    "ytick.left", "ytick.right",

    "axes.spines.left", "axes.spines.bottom",
    "axes.spines.right", "axes.spines.top",]

_context_keys = [
    "font.size", "axes.labelsize",
    "axes.titlesize", "xtick.labelsize",
    "ytick.labelsize", "legend.fontsize",

    "axes.linewidth", "grid.linewidth",
    "lines.linewidth", "lines.markersize",
    "patch.linewidth",

    "xtick.major.width", "ytick.major.width",
    "xtick.minor.width", "ytick.minor.width",

    "xtick.major.size", "ytick.major.size",
    "xtick.minor.size", "ytick.minor.size",]
```

Also note that `set_style` is just a convenience function which calls `axes_style`.

So you will have to use `matplotlib.rcParams`, although if the typical `rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,10]` syntax is not amenable you could of course [create your own style](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style).