# Seaborn cannot override Matplotlib's rcParams['grid.linewidth']

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I am trying to set the grid of a 3D plot using seaborn, such as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white",{"grid.color": "0.2", "grid.linestyle": "-","grid.linewidth": "2"})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
plt.show()
```

The parameter `"grid.linewidth"` does not have any affect on the grid linewidth, however, if I add

```
  plt.rcParams['grid.linewidth'] = 2
```

before I set the figure, then I am able to change the grid thickness. Would anyone be able to explain how to incorporate that into the seaborn function or what I'm doing wrong? It does not matter where I place the rcParam inside the function.

Here is the output regardless of whether I put "2" or "200".

[image: grid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set_context` for this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

sns.set_style("white", {'grid.color': "0.2", "grid.linestyle": "--"})
sns.set_context("notebook", rc={"grid.linewidth": 3})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d grid with linewidth]

`set_style` and `set_context` have these differing explanations for their rc dict, below.

The source code defines the list of [parameters under each category, here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.11.2/seaborn/rcmod.py) and it was also explained in a bit more detail in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878196/seaborn-rc-parameters-for-set-context-and-set-style).

```
<set_style>
rc : dict, optional
    Parameter mappings to override the values in the preset seaborn
    style dictionaries. This only updates parameters that are
    considered part of the style definition.
```

```
<set_context>
rc : dict, optional
    Parameter mappings to override the values in the preset seaborn
    context dictionaries. This only updates parameters that are
    considered part of the context definition.
```