# How to change the font.size for all subplots with sns.set and rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, font-size, subplot

I'm trying to change all font elements in a series of boxplots I'm plotting. My code is similar to

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_group(df, nrow, ncol, size, plot_title):

    sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = size
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, figsize=(15, 10), tight_layout=True)
    fig.suptitle(plot_title)
    n_boxplots = 2
    for i in range(nrow):  
        for j in range(ncol): 
            current_ax = axes[i, j]
            sns.boxplot(data=df[['foo','bar']], palette="Set2", ax=current_ax)
            current_ax.set_title("foo", fontsize=18)

    plt.savefig(f'font_size_{size}.png', dpi=75)
    plt.close(fig)

nrow = 3
ncol = 3
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
arr = rng.random((30, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=['foo', 'bar'])
for size in [14, 22]:

    plot_title = f"Font size = {size}"
    plot_group(df, nrow, ncol, size, plot_title)
```

However, this results in two figures where only the `suptitle` font size changes, but everything else stays the same:

[image]
[image]

Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are many answers dealing with `sns.set`, `sns.set_style`, and `rcParams`.

  - [seaborn rc parameters for `set_context` and `set_style`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60878196/7758804)
  - [Seaborn cannot override `grid.linewidth`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69618816/7758804)
- As shown in the seaborn [rcmod.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12.2/seaborn/rcmod.py) file, `rcParms` are already being set by the seaborn functions.
- `.set` is an alias for `.set_theme`
- Override `rcParams` set by `.set_theme` using the parameters as defined [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12.2/seaborn/rcmod.py#L82-L123).

  - There are [`_context_keys`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12.2/seaborn/rcmod.py#L53-L79) and [`_style_keys`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12.2/seaborn/rcmod.py#L13-L51).
- In the case of this code, remove `sns.set(style="darkgrid")` and `plt.rcParams['font.size'] = size`, and use `sns.set_theme(context={'font.size': size})` instead.

  - Using `rcParams` directly, when using `sns.set_theme`, does not seem to work.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
def plot_group(df, nrow, ncol, size, plot_title):

    sns.set_theme(context={'font.size': size})  # use set_theme
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, figsize=(15, 10))
    axes = axes.flat
    fig.suptitle(plot_title)
    for ax in axes:
        sns.boxplot(data=df, palette="Set2", ax=ax)
        ax.set_title("foo", fontsize=18)

    plt.savefig(f'font_size_{size}.png', dpi=75)
    plt.close(fig)


nrow = 3
ncol = 3
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
arr = rng.random((30, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=['foo', 'bar'])
for size in [14, 22]:
    plot_title = f"Font size = {size}"
    plot_group(df, nrow, ncol, size, plot_title)
```

[image]

[image]